# How to add random number of falling balls in pygame?

Tags: random, pygame

Here is some code for random falling balls, I am able to generate one falling ball. Having hard time to randomize the number of falling balls, also they need to be some random delays falling from "sky". Could you tell how to do it ?

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
 
robot = pygame.image.load("robot.png")
 
y1 = 0
y2 = 0
speed1 = 1
speed2 = 2
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    robots = []
    screen.blit(robot, (100, y1))

    y1 += speed1

    if y1 >= 640:
        y1 = 0

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean by randomly falling balls but to make more balls fall in an irregular manner you could create a for loop which changes the value of y and the x value of the blotted image a little each iteration and blits the ball. the amount by which you change the y and x values can be created using random.randint()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the best solution for your problem. I did a list with position (x, y) and then I used this values in for loop.

Here is code example:

```
balls_num = 100
robots = [[random.randint(0, width), random.randint(-600, 0)] for _ in range(balls_num)]
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for pos in robots:
        screen.blit(robot, (pos[0], pos[1]))
        pos[1] += speed1

        if pos[1] >= 640:
            pos[1] = -100
```

I hope it will help you, Adam